# How to generate Master Pass Merchant ID/Merchant PAN

Tags: payment, pci-compliance, pci-dss, mastercard, core-banking

I am working on Masterpass QR integration which is a scan to pay feature where there will be a user and a merchant.Can anybody let me know the steps or algorithm for generating merchant PAN in masterpass QR.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this MasterCard page](https://mea.mastercard.com/en-region-mea/consumers/masterpass-africaqr.html) (which is for Africa), you don't need to generate anything.  MasterCard generates the QR code and provides it to the merchant, who then displays it.

In general, the merchant identifier (PAN, MID, etc) will be provided to the merchant by their bank, and then entered into their POS or backend - there's nothing for you to generate.